# How to return a sentence with an exact word not as a part of the other word

Tags: python, text

I need to find all sentences with exact word match. Not inside of the other words.

I'm trying this:
`text='He's using apple phone. I like apples. Did you install this app? Apply today!'`

`[sentence + '.' for sentence in text.split('.') if 'app' in sentence]`

I get the output:
`'He's using apple phone. I like apples. Did you install this app? Apply today!'`

but need only:
`Did you install this app?`